# Is it possible to enforce type-safety of generic abstract methods without declared superclass generics?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class ParentClass<T, U> {
    // a bunch of common code to prevent duplication in children
    protected abstract adaptThese(...things: Array<MyType>): Array<T>
    protected abstract adaptThose(...things: Array<MyType>): Array<U>
    // some other non-generic abstract methods
}
```

And here's an example child class:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass<FirstType, SecondType> {
    protected adaptThese(...things: Array<MyType>): Array<FirstType> {
       //...
    }
    protected adaptThose(...things: Array<MyType>): Array<SecondType> {
       //...
    }
    // implementations of the other abstract methods...
}
```

My code is working as-is, but the problem is that all code referring to `ParentClass` has to refer to it as `ParentClass<any, any>`. Since the generic types are purely for internal purposes (`protected` stuff only), I am wondering if there is a good way to remove the generic types from the parent class while still enforcing type safety for the children's use of `<T>` and `<U>`.

I introduced these generics originally to force child classes to provide some kind of adaptation from `MyType` to both `T` and `U`, which are library-dependent and are never `MyType`. The goal was to allow the rest of my project to use `MyType` no matter which underlying library was being used, as they are all very similar in design, but with different types being accepted. This would allow the chosen package to be swapped in or out without affecting code outside this hierarchy. (I am using Angular, so this means just changing the `useClass` of a provider on one line).

I have tried to make some kind of inner adapter object which could contain the generics, but I don't know then how to force the child classes to declare and implement its methods similar to above.

The closest that I got was to add a parameter in `ParentClass`'s constructor of type `MyAdapter<any, any>`, but I couldn't manage to get `any` to become some generic types that would enforce type-safety in the children.

One piece of info which might be really helpful is that `ParentClass` never refers to the generic methods itself, so they don't necessarily need to be declared for `ParentClass` to use. They are just there to force children to implement them. Maybe there is some kind of interface design I can use to accomplish this?

In short: How, if at all, can I force children to implement type-safe methods without declaring the types in the signature of the parent?

---

An example was requested, so here is a simplified examplehow the type-reliance is split:

In `ParentClass`, I may have a method like this:

```
// sets an array of things for a certain key (label)
setThingsFor(label: string) {
    const thingsForLabel: Array<MyType> = myConfiguration.get(label);
    // do some calculations, and filter things based on configuration
    this.setThings(thingsForDisplay);
}

// sets an array of things for the feature
// this is public because the things can be set while avoiding the above calculations and configurations
abstract setThings(things: Array<MyType>): void;
```

And in a child class:

```
public class CoolLibraryImplForParentClass extends ParentClass<CoolType, RadType> {
    setThings(things: Array<MyType>): void {
        // use "things" to determine some library-specific config
        coolLibraryService.initialize(this.adaptThose(things)); // RadType
        coolLibraryService.doThings(this.adaptThese(things));   // CoolType
    }        

    // the generic methods and some CoolLibrary-specific things

}
```

There are many methods like the one above for tooling or requesting state from the library's service(s) which require one of the two types.

And the code for each library is very similar, hence why I introduced a parent class for the project-facing code and had child classes work with library-dependent specifics.

Another consideration I have since made is that I might be able to make a project-facing service class and then have that class be provided a generically-typed library-integrating service, but it's quite a rewrite and I am still interested in the answer to this question.

Comment: With the code as presented, I'd just remove `T` and `U` entirely and have the parent class return `Array<any>`.  If you have some constraint that actually requires the types `T` and `U` (or something like them) then maybe you can add more code that shows these dependencies?

Comment: @jcalz I've added an example, thanks for your interest

Comment: Hmm, I still don't see how `ChildClass` cares about those two specific types, though.  I think at the minimum you'd need to show two different subclass implementations so someone can see what's the same and what's different.  At this point I'd still say that you don't need `T` and `U` and leave it up to the child class implementations to use their libraries however they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to handle this would be to make an interface `IParentClass` which is *not* generic, then refer to `IParentClass` everywhere you were previously referring to `ParentClass<any, any>`.

```
interface IParentClass {
  // all the public methods from ParentClass
}

abstract class ParentClass<T, U> implements IParentClass {
  // same as before
}

// reference like this
var foo: IParentClass;
```

Alternatively, you could provide `any` as a default for the generic type params on `ParentClass`, but this isn't ideal since there's no way to force the child class to provide a proper value for the generic. For example (I introduced some new method signatures to make the problem obvious):

```
abstract class ParentClass<T = any, U = any> {
  protected abstract returnTs(): Array<T>
  protected abstract alsoReturnTs(): Array<T>
  // etc
}

// referencing like this compiles now
var foo: ParentClass;

// This one gets strong typing since it overrides the default `any` generic param type
class GoodChildClass extends ParentClass<string, number> {
  protected returnTs(): Array<string> {
    return ['hello'];
  }
  protected alsoReturnTs(): Array<string> {
    return ['world'];
  }
}

// This one doesn't!
class BadChildClass extends ParentClass {
  protected returnTs(): Array<number> {
    return [1];
  }
  protected alsoReturnTs(): Array<string> {
    return ['oh no'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that, at least for now, your alternative is suitable for my current implementation since there are very few children and the generics still encourage new implementations to add type safety despite it not being required.